# Arrastro commits en git,como solucionarlo?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Estoy arrastro el primer commit que creé entre ramas como puedo cambiarlo??ESto es lo que pasa cuando hago git log

```
commit acc01c4ef1f972cd4656edd6c099090f186e5386 (HEAD -> lab-mysql, origin/lab-mysql)
Author: 
Date:   Wed Jun 10 09:20:37 2020 +0200

    lab7(1)

commit dc3cd341ab7543f45564fd4ed8bccf6b071fe554 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master, lab-list-comprehensions, lab-generators-functions)
Author: 
Date:   Mon Jun 1 21:10:43 2020 +0200

    firstcommit
```

Quiero que tal solo esté el lab7(1)

Comment: No esta muy claro tu problema.

Comment: `git log --first-parent lab-mysql --no-merges`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPCION 1- Para cuando hagas nuevos merge o copiando a una nueva rama**

Con `git merge --squash` puedes hacer que cuando juntas las ramas, desaparezcan tus commits y sólo se guarde el del merge.

Es decir, si hiciste 20 commits en tu rama de desarrollo, cuando la juntes con máster, únicamente quedará el mensaje de commit que escribas en ese momento.

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash lab-mysql
git commit
```

Así harías únicamente commit del último mensaje, y master no tendrá todos los commits.

**OPCION 2 - Para limpiar la rama actual**

Si lo que quieres es eliminar algunos mensajes atrás de una rama ya creada, puedes hacerlo con

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

Esto te proporcionará una lista de commits:

```
abcd1234 Update to Fix for issue B
cdababcd Fix issue B
deab3412 Fix issue A
```

Aquí, deberás elegir el código del commit desde el que necesitas hacer SQUASH:

```
git rebase -i deab3412
```

Ahí te aparecerá un pequeño editor donde podrás elegir qué commits quieres eliminar

```
pick cdababcd Fix issue B
squash abcd1234 Update to Fix for issue B
```

Modifica `pick` por `squash` donde quieras y cierra el editor (con intro o `ctrl+x` )

git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
1122abcd Fix issue B
deab3412 Fix issue A

Y hace el push con `--force`

`git push origin master --force`

Te paso también [de dónde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git) he obtenido parte de la explicación ya que no recordaba el procedimiento completo

> Espero que al menos te sirva de guía. Mucha suerte, y **recuerda siempre
>   guardar una copia de las ramas antes de trastear.**